# To Open Tally ERP 9

Tags: c#, tally

I am using Tally ERP 9 in which i am pushing data into tally programatically using C#. Now my concern is how to open tally with credentials using C# or any other source. So help me with some reference or logic.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is not supported in Tally ERP 9. In other words, you must start Tally and manually enter the credentials to open a Company in Tally. After this, you can push or pull Tally data using XML requests.

XML request for retrieving Tally data: 
https://www.rtslink.com/articles/tally-xml-tags-export/

XML request to import data into Tally: 
https://www.rtslink.com/articles/tally-xml-tags-import/